# Start scheduled jobs in play

Tags: playframework

I have a class like this:

```
package jobs;

import play.jobs.Every;
import play.jobs.Job;

@Every("5s")
public class ScheduledJobs extends Job{

    @Override
    public void doJob(){
        System.out.println("Job's done");
    }

}
```

And the config file contains the following:

```
#Jobs executor
# ~~~~~~
# Size of the Jobs pool
play.jobs.pool=10

# Execution pool
# ~~~~~
# Default to 1 thread in DEV mode or (nb processors + 1) threads in PROD mode.
# Try to keep a low as possible. 1 thread will serialize all requests (very useful for  debugging purpose)
# play.pool=3
```

My question is how can I get play to start running this job every 5 second? If I create a ScheduledJobs instance and I call doJob it runs once only. Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

The ScheduledJobs is placed in a jobs package in my app directory.

I tried everything however the job does not execute (even if I try `@OnApplicationStar` or any other annotation. The job is just not starting. if I call new `ScheduledJobs().now()` I get a null pointer exception at play.jobs.Job.java line 64. (Play 1.2.3).
I need to solve this issue very soon. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call anything in code to get the job to work. After you make your first web request to the server (assuming it's in DEV mode) it will then start executing the Job every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks.
"application.mode=dev" is in my conf file, what happens in prod mode anyways?
But still my job does not start when I make my first request to the server.

Comment: In prod mode it shouldn't wait for the first request I believe. Can you try changing the _@Every_ to use the _@On_ annotation instead, eg. _@On("0 * * * * ?")_ for once per minute

Comment: You can check play status to see whether this job is running or not.

Comment: And where is that James?
Grahamrb I tried what you said but still nothing.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, upload the module zipped up somewhere if you like and I can take a look at the actual code.